# How do I check for a bracket in the file name of the a drag and drop file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have an issue with the drag and drop of an image onto the website where if the file name has a bracket like [  or ] then it causes a problem with the upload.  How do I check to see if the file name has this and if it does then how do I remove it?

```
function process_drop(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation(); 
    evt.preventDefault(); 
    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; 

    //CHECK TO SEE IF FILE NAME HAS A BRACKET ?

    // run through each file individually.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.indexOf("]") != -1
```

indexOf returns the position of the string in the other string. If not found, it will return -1.

from here [JavaScript: string contains](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1789945/103959)

---

For your other questions:

```
var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
//number of files
var count = files.length;
//the first file's info
var first = files[0];
//the first file's name
var name = first.name;
```

I found a pretty good link for you: [HTML5 Drag and drop file api tutorial](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/)

Comment: the file name is within the evt.dataTransfer.files object so how do I access the file name to run this code on it?  There could be many files that the evt.dataTransfer.files object contains.